# Base de Dados com Municipios , Cidade , Bairros

Tags: php, mysql, .net, laravel, oracle

Alguem sabe onde consigo uma base de dados  com 
*Estados
* Municipios 
* Cidade 
* Bairros 
no brasil ?

Comment: https://github.com/chandez/Estados-Cidades-IBGE

Comment: Esta está faltando muitos bairros , procurei 2 bairros antigos da miha cidade e não achei .